# Hyperlinks stop working in firefox after redirect?

Tags: php, firefox, redirect, hyperlink

On a project I'm working on, I am using HTTP headers to redirect the user to the frontpage after a successful login;

```
header("Location: http://example.com/index.php?");
exit(0);
```

*EDIT: Added questionmark to url to show the problem*

This works fine in all browsers tested - however, in Firefox 3.0.6, both on windows, mac and debian, it fails to set the hyperlinks properly. Every single hyperlink points to the same URL the redirect points to, completely ignoring the "`href`" attribute. Refreshing the page does not help - I have to re-enter the URL manually and hit enter for the hyperlinks to start working again.

I've tried this in IE6, IE7, Opera and Safari, and it works fine. I'm assuming something is wrong with the way I implement the redirect, could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you set the HTTP 301/302 status as well?

Comment: I don't set it manually, no. But according to the php manual this should be done automatically (http://se2.php.net/header)

Comment: Is it the first string that your script output?

Comment: Yes, nothing else is printed before the header()-call, and execution is halted directly afterwards.

Comment: Have you set a base URL using the HTML element BASE? Or are you using some extensions that might cause this behavior?

Comment: I just checked some of my scripts and I can only think of a few things. Some of my (working last time I checked) scripts do not exit after sending the header. The ones that do use die. all of my locations redirect to a relative location.

Comment: No base url tag, no extensions. It does, however, redirect to an absolute path, and it redirects to a path ending with ?, which perhaps is causing problems. I'm gonna grab some debugging-whiskey - I'll get back with results!

Comment: In fact the HTTP specification only allows absolute URIs however most clients do also allow relative ones. And exit() is a alias of die() and vice versa. So the code is definetly correct.

Comment: Off-topic nitpicking @Gumbo: How can exit() be an alias of die() *and vice versa*?! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The solution seems to be this:
I cannot redirect to a url ending with a questionmark, if I do, this problem will occur. It would seem to me this is not expected behavior from FF3, but I don't know the HTTP-spec's well enough to say if that's the case.

Either way, **problem solved by removing question-mark from redirect url.**