# ASP .NET 301 redirect create problem for some users

Tags: asp.net, global-asax, http-status-code-301

This is the code I use to redirect from www. to non www. version of my site

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string authority = Request.Url.Authority;
    if (authority.StartsWith("www."))
    {
        authority = authority.Remove(0, 4);
        string newUrl = "http://" + authority + Request.Url.PathAndQuery;

        Response.Clear();
        Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
        Response.AddHeader("Location", newUrl);
        Response.End();            
    }
}
```

this is the tool I used to validate if the code above work as expected:

> http://www.internetofficer.com/seo-tool/redirect-check/

While everything works as expected for almost all users, some of them has complained they can't access the site. I logged in to their computer using TeamViewer and indeed, there was a problem. When they try to acces the site, FF and IE gives an error: it looks like the site you wanted isn't there.

What should be the problem ?

Comment: This should really be handled by your DNS records, not in code.  That is the SEO-friendliest way.

Comment: Can those machines browse directly to the version withou the `www.` prefix?

Comment: How do you do a redirect with a DNS record, martin?

Comment: No, they can directly browse the non www version. The same error appear. I want to be a SEO friendly redirect, that's why I want a 301 redirect. All of you must known about www. and non www sites and how Google treat this as duplicate content.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `.PathAndQuery`, so take a look into this answer: [Hyperlinks stop working in firefox after redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526114/hyperlinks-stop-working-in-firefox-after-redirect)

> problem solved by removing question-mark from redirect url.

So, try to use `Request.Url.LocalPath` property.

Comment: I want to redirect users to the same page, but wihtout www. in the URL. From "http:// www.example.com/Home.aspx?id=2" to "http:// example.com/Home.aspx?id=2"

Comment: Can you remove the trailing question mark if it ends the url?
Something like:
if(newUrl.EndsWith("?")) newUrl = newUrl.Substring(0, newUrl.Length - 2);
That should only remove empty query strings, while leaving ?id=2.